# Connection with Zk tech C3 400 Device

Tags: python-3.x, zkteco

I am trying to connect with my Zk tech C3 400 using python. I have tried with pyzkacess(https://pypi.org/project/pyzkaccess/) and pyzk(https://pypi.org/project/pyzk/)
with both I am getting timout in both the libraries with pyzkaccess I got TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Mock' and 'int' python zk Can you someone please help.

```
   from zk import ZK, const

   conn = None
   # create ZK instance
   zk = ZK('192.168.1.201', port=4370, timeout=5, password=0, force_udp=False, ommit_ping=False)
  try:
     # connect to device
     conn = zk.connect()
     # disable device, this method ensures no activity on the device while the process is run
     conn.disable_device()

  except Exception as e:
     print ("Process terminate : {}".format(e))
  finally:
     if conn:
        conn.disconnect()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That library uses a custom ZKTeco protocol based on UDP, and its mainly used for time-attandance devices. C3 Panels use a protocol based on TCP called pullsdk, and it's used for access-control.

[These dlls](https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper/tree/main/lib) are pullsdk, and as far as I know the only SDK for C3 & inbio devices. The only supported platform is win_x86. So you have to call native dlls form python.
You will find usage examples in this [github repo](https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper).